# Proof that there is a basis in $H$ s.t $f(\sum_{i}^{}{x_ih_i}) =x_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a problem with the following statement I don't see why it's exactly true, any hint would be a lot appreciated.

Let $f$ a linear form ( in a finite vector space ).

> There is a basis $h_1, ... , h_n \in H \;\text{s.t}\:\forall x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{K} \: \:\text{,}\;f(\sum_{i}^{}{x_ih_i})=x_1$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f : H \to \mathbb{K}$ is a non-zero linear form, where $H$ is a $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$vector space.
Let $(h_2,\ldots,h_n)$ be a basis of $\ker f$, which is $n-1$ dimensional if $f$ is a non-zero linear form. Chose a vector $h_1$ such that $f(h_1)= 1$ (it exists because $f$ is non-zero, and thus surjective). Then $(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$ is a basis of $H$, and if $v = \sum_{i=1}^n x_ih_i$, then
\begin{align}
f(v) = f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i h_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_if(h_i) = x_1
\end{align}